# Small bug on "Traditional view" of Developer Story site

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story, traditional-view

This is a very small bug so I don't know if it's worth mentioning.

On the "Traditional view" of Stack Overflow's *Developer Story* at the **Job Status** section, there is a missing space.

To recreate you need to be logged in, on your own Developer Story in the 'Traditional View'-tab with 'Job Preferences' set to "Not interested in jobs".

As seen here:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's it.. This site is ruined for me. Time to delete my account, I mean, if a site can't even handle simple spaces, what else can't they handle!?!

Comment: Well if you don't want to work with python, why are you so whitespace-sensitive?  (That sounded more clever before I typed it.)

Comment: @BJMyers Bash is kinda sensitive about missing spaces though ...

Comment: We would really appreciate a response from a SE employee on this matter!!

Comment: Easy fix: stop blocking all message and searches.

Comment: @AlexL If this is how you debug stuff, may God have mercy on your soul.

Comment: As expected, [it took about 6-8 months to fix this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/360193/revisions/#revisions)