# Missing space in developer profile job status

Tags: bug

I just cleared my developer story because it was fairly empty and I'm not particularly interested in the functionality, after doing so I went onto my preferred *Traditional view* and saw that in the job status section, there's a sentence that is clearly missing a space. This only applies to the *"Not interested in jobs"* job preference.

[image]

Can we put a space between *to* and ***block***.

This is using Chrome 63.0.3239.108 on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

Comment: I'd like to message you about a QA job since you seem you would be good at it, but your profile is set toblock messages

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360193/small-bug-on-traditional-view-of-developer-story-site

Comment: @Andreas Well found